# Lost all my reputation

Tags: support, bug, reputation

I've refreshed the page after some time on stackoverflow and all my reputation is reset. I saw a "-4600" notification and I was back to 100 or something (I was around 4600 before).

Also the username and real names were different (something like user984398). The only thing I remember doing was I changed my real name.

I can see all my answers though and still have my badges. And the log in here: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation looks fine.

My profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242778/agis

Comment: Looking fine to me...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just fixed!

Comment: Hmmm think I know what's causing this now

Comment: @NickCraver I think it has to do with the fact that I've edited my profile plus the other stackexchange networks.

Comment: @NickCraver we are waiting with bated breath

Comment: @Agis nope, it's the fact that one of your posts was used as an audit in the review queue, analyzing and fixing now

Comment: @Nick wow, "the audit that killed my rep"... good title for a book, or horror movie! :-P

Comment: @NickCraver: Damnit, I told you guys to stop doing that!  Y U NO LISTEN!